# Is U=V in the SVD of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, svd, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Consider the SVD of matrix $A$:

$$A = U \Sigma V^\top$$

If $A$ is a symmetric, positive semidefinite real matrix, is there a guarantee that $U = V$?

Second question (out of curiosity): what is the minimum necessary condition for  $U = V$?

Answer (score 15):

Here is an attempt to provide a clear answer, building upon [Arash's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928014/769194).

Primer:

- Any matrix $A$ can be decomposed with Singular Value Decomposition (SVD) as $A = U \Sigma V^\top$. $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices. This decomposition is not unique: the singular values part $\Sigma$ is unique ; however the signs in the left and right singular vectors can be interchanged. Besides when at least one singular value is zero, there are many possible corresponding singular vectors. The following hold ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition)):

  - the singular values are equal to the square roots of the eigenvalues of $AA^\top$ (or the ones of $A^\top A$) (resp. $AA^*$ or $A^*A$ for complex matrices)
  - the right singular vectors (columns of $V$) are eigenvectors of $A^\top A$ (resp. $A^*A$)
  - the left singular vectors (columns of $U$) are eigenvectors of $AA^\top$ (resp. $AA^*$)
- if $A$ is **real symmetric** then (spectral theorem) it is diagonalizable and therefore has at least one eigendecomposition $A = Q \Lambda Q^{-1} = Q \Lambda Q^\top $. ([this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/125975/156452) shows a non-diagonalizable counterexample of a complex symmetric matrix). In general this decomposition is not unique: the eigenvalues part $\Lambda$ is unique ; however the eigenvectors part $Q$ is only unique if no eigenvalue is zero.
- so, if $A$ is **real symmetric**

  - its singular values are the absolute values (modulus if complex) of its eigenvalues.
  - both the right and left singular vectors (columns of $V$ and $U$) are eigenvectors of $A^\top A = AA^\top = A^2 = Q \Lambda^{2} Q^{-1}$, so they are both eigenvectors of $A$. Also, remember that they are unit vectors: so they are either equal to vectors in $Q$ or to $-1$ times these vectors.

Now to translate this in an answer to your question:

- if $A$ is **real symmetric** and **positive definite** (i.e. all of its eigenvalues are strictly positive), $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues, and $U=V$.
- if $A$ is **real symmetric** and only **semi-positive definite** (i.e. all of its eigenvalues are positive but some of its eigenvalues can be zero), $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues, but there is **no guarantee** that $U=V$. Indeed the part of $U$ and $V$ corresponding to the zero eigenvalues can be any orthonormal decomposition of the null space of $A$, with sign flips allowed independently on $U$ and $V$.
- if $A$ is only **real symmetric** and **not semi-positive definite** (i.e. some of its eigenvalues can be negative), then $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix containing the **absolute values** of the eigenvalues. There are then two reasons for there being **no guarantee** that $U=V$. If there is a zero eigenvalue, then see previous bullet point. If there is a negative eigenvalue, then the sign "taken off" the eigenvalue in $\Lambda$ to construct the (positive by definition) $\Sigma$ to make it positive has to end up either on $U$ or $V$. For a concrete example consider a diagonal matrix with at least one negative element.

As noted by [Arash](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1928014/769194) you can replace in all the above statements the words "real symmetric" with ["normal"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix).

So to conclude a minimum condition for $U=V$ is to be **normal** and **positive definite**. Now is this necessary ? Is it proven that non-normal matrices can not have strictly positive eigenvalues ? This is the part I'm not sure about.

Comment: Thank you for the intuitive, educational and elaborate explanation.

Comment: You're welcome ! Thanks for the feedback @SohailSi

Comment: @smarie I can't understand why the spectral theorem says $U = V$ as you mentioned. Could you explain this more, please?

Comment: @Figurinha can you tell which part of the answer is not clear enough ?

Comment: @smarie I know that the spectral theorem says we have a decomposition $A = QDQ^T$, where $D$ is diagonal with its elements being the eigenvalues of $A$ and that $Q^TQ = QQ^T = I$, but I can't see why this implies $U = V$ in the SVD... What is not clear for me is: if $A = U \Sigma V^T$ and $A = QDQ^T$, with $\Sigma = D$, why should $U = V$? Why couldn't we have different decompositions for $A$ such that $A = UDV^T$ and also $A = QDQ^T$?

Comment: I edited the answer, it should now be clearer that elements in U and V are eigenvectors of A in that case, and they are unit vectors - so there are not many degrees of freedom left than changing the sign (phase if complex).

Comment: Normal + positive definite implies Hermitian. A normal matrix is unitarily diagonalizable by the spectral theorem (this is actually an equivalence), and it is positive definite if and only if its eigenvalues are real and positive, which implies that it is Hermitian.

Answer (score 7):

First of all see that $U$ and $V$ are not unique in general. However you might be able to find a relation between distinct SVD of a matrix $A$ and working with real matrix makes things easier.

For a general real $A$, let singular values of $A$ be non-zero. If $A=U_1\Sigma V_1^T$ and $A=U_2\Sigma V_2^T$ then from [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-on-non-unique-are-u-and-v-in-singular-value-decomposition-svd), there is a diagonal matrix $D=\mathrm{diag}(\pm 1,\dots,\pm 1)$ such that:
$$
U_1=U_2D, V_1=V_2D.
$$
Now suppose that $A$ is a normal matrix with positive eigenvalues. It can be orthogonally diagonalized. Then we can see that:
$$
A=UDU^{T}
$$
This is a SVD of $A$. So for $A=U_1\Sigma V_1^T$ then $U_1=UD$ and $V_1=UD$ which implies that $U_1=V_1$. In other words having normal matrix with positive eigenvalues is sufficient for having $U=V$. This class includes  positive definite matrices. When zero singular values are permitted, then the situation is more tricky. Take zero matrix for instance.

Answer (score 3):

If the matrix is symmetric then $U=V$, as the by the spectral theorem we know that the eigenvalue decomposition and the singular value decomposition must be the same. From that we see that $U = U\Lambda U^{-1}=U\Lambda U^T=U\Sigma V^T$, and as by the theorem $\Sigma = \Lambda$ then $U=V$.

Comment: your counter example is not symmetric

Comment: That's why it does not hold that $U=V$

Comment: in the question it says $A$ is symmetric...

Comment: Ok, I didn't read that, I'll edit now

Comment: Why does $V \Sigma U^t = U \Sigma V^t$ tell you that $U = V$?

Comment: Because if A symmetric, then it is equal to it's transpose, so if we do the svd of the transpose we should get the same decomposition as A. Then if we do the decomposition of $A^T$ and we get that it's U matrix is the V matrix, then they should be equal.

Comment: $U$ and $V$ of SVD are not unique in general. By transpose you might recover another SVD; see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644327/how-unique-on-non-unique-are-u-and-v-in-singular-value-decomposition-svd

Comment: However, by the spectral theorem, a symmetric matrix will have real valued eigenvlaues, making the eigenvalue decomposition and the singular value decomposition the same for a symmetric matrix, so even if the svd is not unique, U and V should be the same.

Comment: If $A=U\Sigma V$ then $A=(-U)\Sigma(-V)$ but $U\neq -U$. Again check the question I posted.

Comment: I see that, but what I am saying is that if the eigenvalue decomposition and the svd are the same (thing that happens for symmetric matrices, from the spectral theorem), then U=V. $A=U\Sigma V^T = U\Lambda U^{-1}$, and from spectral theorem: $\Sigma = \Lambda$, $U^{-1}=U^T$, so then U=V.

Comment: I corrected the answer according to what I just stated.

Comment: Why $A=U\Sigma V^T = U\Lambda U^{-1}$? It is more $A=U\Sigma V^T = U_1\Lambda U_1^{T}$ for a $U_1$ that is possibly distinct from $U$ and $V$.

Comment: yes, $U_1$ can be different to $U$, but as the singular values and the eigenvalues are the same, then the form of the decomposition has to be the same, implying that right and left singular vector have to be the same for the singular value decomposition.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22825/how-to-compute-svd-singular-value-decomposition-of-a-symmetric-matrix

Comment: But it has to be rigorously proved that "their form has to be the same". And what do you mean by "the same" singular vectors? You can talk about equivalent singular vectors with proper notion of equivalence.

Comment: This answer is incorrect to me. Consider a diagonal matrix with at least one negative number on it: it is symmetric, but U is different from V in the SVD decomposition (sign flip). See my answer below https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3683742/769194

Answer (score 1):

Self-anwer:

Firstly, note the emphasis on being positive semi-definite. As others said correctly, if $\mathbf A$ is singular, there is no such guarantee, and $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ can be different. As @Arash said, consider zero matrix, the SVD is not unique.

However, if we consider the column space or span of $\mathbf A$, and project $\mathbf U$ and $\mathbf V$ on this space, the projected U and V are equal.

It seems non-singularity also provides the **necessary** condition for $\mathbf U=\mathbf V$. But I need to double-check this.

- Positive semi-definite: No.
- Positive-definite: Yes. (**Sufficient**)

The next question could be, what is (are) the minimum necessary conditions for U=V? (not just a sufficient condition, e.g. pos-def ).