# If $A$ is a symmetric positive-definite matrix then $U = V$ in the SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, svd

> **What I have:**
>
> $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a symmetric positive-definite
> matrix and has Singular Value Decomposition $A = U\Sigma V^T$.

**What I want:** prove that $U = V$.

---

*Also... does $A$ has to be positive-definite for this to be true?*

---

***Edit:** There is the exactly same question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927845/is-u-v-in-the-svd-of-a-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrix), but none of the answers there satisfy my doubts. I'm talking in comments with people here and there. If I come up with a detailed enough answer I might write it there. But I suggest also reading the comments on my question here, they are helpful.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is $U=V$ in the SVD of a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1927845/is-u-v-in-the-svd-of-a-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrix)

Comment: @FBruzzesi Thanks! I hadn't found this question before... It's exactly my question. But the answers there aren't suficient for me. How should I answer the community member suggestion?

Comment: Try to show that if $U\ne V$ then the product is not symmetric. Remember that $(ABC)^\top = C^\top B^\top A^\top,$ i.e. the order of multiplication get reversed.

Comment: An alternative route that gives some useful results along the way: use SVD to construct the Polar decomposition for any square matrix  (i.e. SVD implies existence of Polar decompostion). Then prove the Polar decomposition is unique for any invertible . Set := and if ≠ then you'd have (at least) two distinct polar decompositions for , which is impossible since  is invertible. If we relax the PD criterion for :  in general you lose uniqueness considerations when dealing with singular matrices; and if  is indefinite then U=V  implies A is PD so ≠

Comment: @MichaelHardy That isn't exactly true. For instance, the product is still symmetric when $U = -V$. Things get even more complicated if $A$ is not necessarily invertible