# Singular Values of Symmetric Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, singular-values

I saw the following claim in this thread:

[How to compute the SVD of a symmetric matrix?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22825/how-to-compute-the-svd-of-a-symmetric-matrix)

> **Claim:**  The singular values of a symmetric matrix $A$ are the absolute values of its eigenvalues.

I understand why is it true for positive definite symmetric matrices as their be orthogonal diagonalization and SVD are the same.

But how can I prove it for a symmetric matrix which is not necessarily positive definite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A=UDU^*$ be the orthogonal diagonalization, where
$$
D = \mathrm{diag}(s_1,\dots,s_k,s_{k+1},\dots,s_n)
$$
with $s_1,\dots,s_k\geq 0$ and $s_{k+1},\dots,s_n<0$.

Let $V$ be the matrix with the same firs $k$ columns as $U$ and the last $n-k$ columns which are the opposite as those of $U$:
$$
V=(u_1,\dots,u_k,-u_{k+1},\dots,-u_n),
$$
where $U=(u_1,\dots,u_n)$. Moreover, let
$$
\Sigma = \mathrm{diag}(s_1,\dots,s_k,-s_{k+1},\dots,-s_n).
$$
Then $V$ is also orthogonal and $A=U\Sigma V^*$ is the SVD of $A$.

Comment: Simple and concise. Thank you!