# What does it mean if U = -V' when doing SVD?

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

I calculated the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) (SVD) of a square matrix, $A = U\Sigma V^{\intercal}$. I noticed that the unitary matrices $U$ and $V^{\intercal}$ satisfy $U = -V^{\intercal}$. What property of the original matrix $A$ leads to this outcome?

Edit: I think it might be that $A$ is a symmetric matrix, based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22832/406393).

Comment: Was the matrix of interest antisymmetric?

Comment: If it were $U=-V$ instead, then $A=U \Sigma V^\top = U (-\Sigma) U^\top$ so $A$ is symmetric with nonpositive eigenvalues. However, $U=-V$ is not $U=-V^\top$, so this is a different condition.